# Add wrapper to all Devise Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, wrapper

I'm using Devise with Rails 3.1 and I have generated all the views for Devise.

I want any Devise view to be wrapped in a div:

```
<div class="devise-container">
  <!-- Devise view -->
</div>
```

At the moment I have manually added this to every Devise view, but this is not very DRY. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Devise controllers and have not overridden them, you can create a layout called "devise.html.haml" or "devise.html.erb" (or whatever templating language you use) in the usual app/views/layouts/ directory and add the custom code you need.

This layout should then automatically get loaded and override you application controller because the layout name matches the controller name.

However, that said, a better solution may be to add a class to the  tag of your application layout with the current controller name (*controller.name*) and use CSS to manage the problem by adding a custom style only to "body.devise" pages.  This solution is more flexible and adds less clutter to your application code, seeing as it is a presentation problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are not. Or you can do some view refactoring.

Install view from devise it's exactly the same than create new view file.

In View refactoring you can do some helper to do this particular div. Or do some "layout"

Answer (score 0):

I created a _devise-wrapper-start.html.erb in views/layouts with

`<div class="devise-container">`

and a _devise-wrapper-end.html.erb with
    `</div>`
and then in every view i put

```
<%= render 'layouts/devise-wrapper-start' %>
```

at the beginning and

```
<%= render 'layouts/devise-wrapper-end' %>
```

at the end.

This is more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) than just putting HTML inside devise views.

When i change the devise wrapper it changes in every view and i don't have to modify every view manually.

This is an half solution, but i didn't find any better.